# Why does an inverted bullet not "unwound" non inverted people?

Tags: tenet

Early in the movie *Tenet* it is established that an inverted bullet while flying backwards from the hole in the floor into the gun "normally" penetrates and kills an uninverted human that is in the way.

Later in the movie an inverted man develops a wound out of nowhere that gets more and more serious until the point of bleeding. He than has a fight with an uninverted enemy that "unwounds" him.

Now what if an inverted man shoots an uninverted and the bullet stays in the body? Shouldn't in this case the uninverted have the bullet all along in his body (appearing mysteriously? Together with the wound?) and the shot should "unwound" him? Then why should this be different when the bullet does not stick? Shouldn't the man in the opera already lie down on the floor bleeding and with a hole in his body, than mysteriously "fall up" and the bullet penetrating his body in reverse unwounding him?

Is this an inconsistency/error? Or is there an explanation for this?

Comment: It is just a good show, take it easy ))

Comment: You are right. In fact, I enjoyed the movie. And while watching it, several times I thought they got it wrong, reviewed the scene, wrapped my brain the other way around and thought "Damn. The are right." I also heared that Nolan had Kip Thorne as consultant. So I assumed they had the ambition to get it right and maybe I missed something or it is explained in interviews.